# How to write a conditional lambda in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lambda, syntax, functional-programming

I'd like to write a conditional lambda in Ruby. The Python equivalent of what I'd like to write is:

```
even = (lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else 0)
```

My attempt to write this in Ruby looks like:

```
even = -> (x) {x if x % 2 == 0 else 0}
```

Unfortunately, that does not work. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options here to express this. The long-form is this:

```
if (x % 2 == 0)
  x
else
  0
end
```

Note that a trailing `if` or `unless` cannot have a secondary condition like `else`. You need to use the full form.

If you want a short version, you use the *ternary operator*:

```
(x % 2 == 0) ? x : 0
```

What you could also do is this:

```
(x % 2 == 0) and x or 0
```

As others have observed there's a method called [`even?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-even-3F) which does the modulo for you, so that can collapse this further:

```
x.even? ? x : 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's ternary operator has this syntax

```
x % 2 == 0 ? x : 0
```

Comment: You could also write `lambda do |x| if x.even? then x else 0 end end`. Many options in Ruby; scrub your brain clean of TIOOWTDI :P

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a conditional.

```
p = ->(x) { x*(1-x%2) }

p.call(4) #=> 4
p.call(5) #=> 0
```

Note procs can be called in multiple ways:

```
p[4]       #=> 4
p.(4)      #=> 4
p.yield(4) #=> 4
p === 4    #=> 4
p(4)       #=> 4
```

The last of these may be archaic.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax. You can write it like this:

```
even = -> (x) {if x % 2 == 0; x; else; 0; end}
```

However, for such one-liners, it is more common to use the ternary ?: operator, as other have suggested in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong:

- The *then*-block comes after the condition, not before it.
- The *then*-block is separated from the condition by the `then` keyword, a semicolon, or a newline.
- The conditional expression is terminated with an `end` keyword.

So, any of the following is valid:

```
# idiomatic:
if x % 2 == 0 then x else 0 end

# idiomatic:
if x % 2 == 0
  x
else
  0
end

# non-idiomatic:
if x % 2 == 0; x else 0 end

# non-idiomatic:
if x % 2 == 0 then
  x
else
  0
end

# non-idiomatic:
if x % 2 == 0
  x else 0 end

# … and many other non-idiomatic variations
```

Ruby also has a conditional operator:

```
x % 2 ? x : 0
```

But I personally find it ugly and unreadable. It also has different precedence than the conditional expression, which may be surprising to some. (Witness the myriad of variations of the same question about the conditional operator here on StackOverflow.) And it is completely unnecessary: in C, where `if` is a conditional statement, the conditional operator is required because it is an expression. In Ruby, everything is an expression anyway, there are no statements, so of course `if` is an expression, too.